# Select a part of Excel Cell (Not Complete Cell) and compare it to other cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have part of a code for VBA to run and add blank rows after it finds non-sequential numbers in my data. However my data contains letters and the way the code is written it only compares integer sequences. Is there a way to manipulate the code to only select part of the cell and compare that part?

For example I have the following sequence:

```
100-CG-000-10008
100-CG-000-10009
100-CG-000-10011
100-CG-000-10012
```

and the idea is to get VBA to insert a blank row after **100-CG-000-10009** due to the fact that it is no longer in sequence after that. The code I'm working with is:

```
Sub InsertNullBetween()
  'Update 20130829
  Dim WorkRng As Range
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim outArr As Variant
  Dim dic As Variant
  Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  'On Error Resume Next
  xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
  Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
  Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
  num1 = WorkRng.Range("A1").Value
  num2 = WorkRng.Range("A" & WorkRng.Rows.Count).Value
  interval = num2 - num1
  ReDim outArr(1 To interval + 1, 1 To 2)
  For Each Rng In WorkRng
    dic(Rng.Value) = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
  Next
  For i = 0 To interval
    If dic.Exists(i + num1) Then
      outArr(i + 1, 1) = i + num1
      outArr(i + 1, 2) = dic(i + num1)
    Else
      outArr(i + 1, 1) = ""
      outArr(i + 1, 2) = ""
    End If
  Next
  With WorkRng.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), UBound(outArr, 2))
    .Value = outArr
    .Select
  End With
End Sub
```

Is there any way I can change the code to only look at the last part of the cell containing the integers after the 3rd "-"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit** with a code to only insert lines and handle whatever gap

you could use this

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertNullBetween()
    Dim i As Long, gap As Long

    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
        For i = .Rows.count To 2 Step -1
            gap = Right(.Cells(i), 5) - Right(.Cells(i - 1), 5)
            If gap > 1 Then .Cells(i).Resize(gap - 1).Insert xlDown
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Pvelez_3, did you get through it?

Comment: hi @user3598756 , the first section of code that you gave me worked however if I have a sequence of numbers that have skipped more than one number it does not add a blank row for every number skipped. How can I get it to do that? For example, if the sequence was 1,2,3,4,7 I would need the code to add a blank space row 5 and row 6.

Comment: The code is not split into two section, while there are two codes: the 1st for gaps of 1 number only and the 2nd for gaps greater than 1. So if your case is to have gaps greater than 1 you must use the 2nd code. Try and let me know

Comment: Do While Right(.Cells(i), 5) - Right(.Cells(i - 1), 5) > 1

Comment: when code stops there 1) click "debug" button 2) type in immediate window `?i, .Cells(i)` 3) press return and see the outcome 4) type in immediate window `?i-1, .Cells(i-1)` 5) press return and see the outcome

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking me to do. When I select "debug" the entire line of code is highlighted. where is it that you want me to add steps 2 and 4 in?

Comment: In the "Immediate Window" (CTRL+G to pop it out)

Comment: Ok, I've tried that and it still did not work. it just seemed to return the files from which the sequence is no longer consecutive. The code to handle gaps with only number missing worked just fine. Is there a way to get the second code to do the same but for gaps greater than one?

Comment: To understand what's going on I need to know what are the exact values returned by those teo statements in Immediate Window (four values, two for each statement). The second code works for me for gaps greater than one

Comment: Ok I understand now. This is what I get when I run that code: 
?i, .Cells(i)
 4            25697-100-DB-35C01-6
?i-1, .Cells(i-1)
 3            25697-100-DB-35C01-00003
And for some reason when I first run the code it takes 25697-100-DB-35C01-00006 and changes it to 25697-100-DB-35C01-6

Comment: My code works with data as per your example, i.e. the "number" part is 5 characters long (if data is `100-CG-000-10008`, "number" is `10008`). While your last example in comment says you have data like `25697-100-DB-35C01-6` where the "number" part is one character long (`6`). So what is the real format of your data? What's the rule to take the "number" out of them?

Comment: I have a large amount of data that I will be using this code on. After a few test runs I have noticed that the code to insert a row for gaps greater than one does not add a blank row (which is what I need it to do) but instead it automatically fills it in with the next number in the sequence which is not what I am looking for. To answer your question regarding the **25697-100-DB-35C01-6** number, my data always has 5 numbers long to begin with but sometimes the number has leading zeros i.e **25697-100-DB-35C01-00006** and when I run your code it is changing that number to 25697-100-DB-35C01-6

Comment: I think the problem here is that 1. the code does not account for leading zeros as part of the 5 numbers and 2. the code does not add a blank space instead it will just add the following number in the sequence automatically.

Comment: It worked!! I have one last question. Is there a way that I can get it to where when I run the code it'll take me back to the spreadsheet and ask have me select the range of cells I'm looking to manipulate? the code I was using before had me do that and it was very helpful @user3598756

Comment: if it worked please mark answer as  accepted. thank you. As for the _new_ issue let me think over it a while...

Comment: I was able to figure out how to make it ask me for a range of cells by parts of code from the original code I had but now the `gap = Right(.Cells(i), 5) - Right(.Cells(i - 1), 5)` line is throwing a Type mismatch error. Any idea on that?

Comment: you'd better add details of what's happening before the code I provided you. as a blind guess I'd say your code is switching between sheets so that all ranges must be fully referenced up to their parent worksheet. for instance change `With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))` to `With Worksheets("mySheetName").Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))` where you have to change "mySheetName" to your actual sheet name to be processed by the code

Comment: I've updated my question to include the new code that I am working with. The code works if I copy part of the column and paste that into a new sheet (which I have been doing as a test) but when I go to use it on the original column that has over 15,000 rows I get the error I mentioned before. I just tried changing the code to match your previous comment but I still get that mismatch error.

Comment: well you'd better leave this post as it was before your last edit so as to have people read a question and its corresponding answer and make a new post with the new issue along with its relevant code and your efforts

Comment: Right I just wanted to show you what I was working with. Is this something you could help me with as well? Should I tag you in the new post? @user3598756

Comment: When you post it just advise me with a comment here

Comment: I have posted the new question. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks too complicated for the task. Here I will only give you the way to extract the last number following the last "-" from your cell:

```
Function ExtractNumber(r As Range) As Long
    ExtractNumber = Mid(r.Value, 1 + InStrRev(r.Value, "-"))
End Function
```

Supposing your current code works well if those cells where pure numbers, you can use this function to customize it. For example:

```
num1= ExtractNumber(WorkRng.Range("A1"))
num2 = ExtractNumber(WorkRng.Range("A" & WorkRng.Rows.Count))
...
dic(ExtractNumber(Rng)) = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

etc..